# Trigger not updating a record field

Tags: apex, trigger, field-update, before-trigger

In my code

```
trigger ContactRole on Application__c (before update) {

            DateTime lastRecordCreated = lastRecord.Created_Date__c;
            System.debug('lastRecordCreated ' + lastRecordCreated);

            DateTime lastAmRecordCreated = lastCCRiskAndChecked.Created_Date__c;
            System.debug('lastAmRecordCreated ' + lastAmRecordCreated);
            
            Double workingHours = calculateWorkingHours(lastRecordCreated, lastAmRecordCreated);
            System.debug('workingHours ' + workingHours);

            Id ccAppId = lastAmRecordCreated.Id;
            
            List<Application__c> ccAppList = [SELECT CalculatedWorkingHours__c from Application__c where id = :ccAppId];

            Application__c appRecord = ccAppList.get(0);

            appRecord.CalculatedWorkingHours__c = workingHours;
            System.debug('appRecord.CalculatedWorkingHours__c ' + appRecord.CalculatedWorkingHours__c);
}
```

I'm using the before update trigger in order to populate the calculated working hours into a custom field called "CalculatedWorkingHours__c".

I can see in the debug log that the  "CalculatedWorkingHours__c" field is updated

> USER_DEBUG [184]|DEBUG|workingHours 17.5
>
> USER_DEBUG [194]|DEBUG|ccAppRecord.CalculatedWorkingHours__c 17.5

but on a record level the field remains blank

Please advise how to be able to solve such issue?

Comment: only `trigger.new` will be updated automatically in a before update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never commit the updated data to the database. Doing so is as simple as calling `insert appRecord;` after you set the value for that variable.

A better idea is to modify the record in the trigger context, allowing the trigger to continue with the DML operation with the updated field value. I've included an example below.

```
trigger ContactRole on Application__c (before update) {
    for (Application__c application:trigger.new) {
        application.CalculatedWorkingHours__c = calculateWorkingHours(application.CreatedDate, lastCCRiskAndChecked.Created_Date__c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to upsert appRecord. As trigger is on application__c object. If any record is queried inside trigger (that is case of apprecord) you have to explicitly upset that record.